# switchbox change state on rotation

Tags: android, rotation, switch-statement, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I develop a simple table-app, and the problem is, that the switch-box will change the state or doesn't reset the state correcly on change rotation.

befor rotating it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIBmc.png)
after rotating it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua3Oq.png)

The hint state will set correct on change but the box is not displayed correctly. What has gone wrong? Actually the views should be updated on any changes in the same way...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/tv_outputItemBoolean"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:trackTint="@color/switch_track_selector"
        android:thumbTint="@color/switch_thumb_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2.5dp"
        android:paddingTop="2.5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>


fun getView(position: Int, rowView: TableRow?, parent: TableLayout): TableRow {

        val rowView = TableRow(parent!!.context)
        val rowData = this.getItem(position)

        for (i in 0..columnCounts - 1) {
            var data: ColumnData<*>? = rowData[i]
            rowView.addView(this.getColumnView(data, null, rowView))
        }

        return rowView
    }

private fun getColumnView(
        col: ColumnData<*>?,
        resycleView: View?,
        parent: ViewGroup
    ): View {

        return when (col?.type) {
            DataType.TimeStamp -> {
                val view = TimeStampPicker.View(parent.context)
                view.timeStampPicker.timeStampInMillis = col.data as Long
                view
            }
            DataType.Boolean ->
            {
                val c= parent.context
                val view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(c)
                        .inflate(R.layout.output_item_boolean, null)
                val switch: Switch = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_outputItemBoolean)

                val value = col.data as Boolean
                var state = switch.isChecked

                Log.v("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", value.toString()+","+state.toString())

                switch.isChecked=value

                 state = switch.isChecked
                Log.v("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", value.toString()+","+state.toString())

                switch.hint=c.getText(DataType.stringResourceOf(value))
                view

            }
            else -> {
                val view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.ouput_item_simple_text, null)
                val tv: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_outputItemSimpleText)
                tv.text = if (col != null) col.data.toString() else "NULL"
                view
            }
        }
    }
```

the output log print shows the right state befor and after setting.

```
V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: false,false
V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: false,false
V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: true,false
V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: true,true
V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: true,false
V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: true,true
V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: false,false
V/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: false,false
```

Comment: this should help you: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states 
activities are destroyed when configuration changes (such as rotation) occur - so you need to be able to rebuild the UI the way the user left it.

Comment: thanks,

It looks like the status of the switch box was only saved for the first switch and was initialized with this when rotating. I moved the call of the setter method from onCreate() to onResume(). now its works.